# Update user Profile in asp.net mvc model is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm a beginner to ASP.NET MVC.

I want to update login user profile and I am having a problem.  my code says model state is not valid. I've tried every possible solution which I know and also searched on Google.

I'm using Entity Framework and below is my code.

Table name: `Userdb`

Get action method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult EditProfile()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;

    Userdb user = db.Userdbs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.u_Email.Equals(username));
           
    Userdb model = new Userdb();

    // Personal Details
    model.u_Firstname = user.u_Firstname;
    model.u_lastname = user.u_lastname;
    model.u_dob = user.u_dob;
    model.u_mobile = user.u_mobile;
    model.u_title = user.u_title;

    // this to display data in texbox
    ViewBag.u_Email = user.u_Email;
    ViewBag.u_Firstname = user.u_Firstname;
    ViewBag.u_lastname = user.u_lastname;
    ViewBag.u_dob = user.u_dob;
    ViewBag.u_mobile = user.u_mobile;
    ViewBag.u_title = user.u_title;

    // Education Details
    model.Degree_level = user.Degree_level;
    model.Degree_name = user.Degree_name;
    model.Starting_date = user.Starting_date;
    model.Completion_date = user.Completion_date;  

    // Address Details 
    model.country_name = user.country_name;
    model.city_name = user.city_name;
    model.Address = user.Address;
    model.postal_code = user.postal_code;    

    // Social Link Details
    model.S_fb_url = user.S_fb_url;
    model.S_linkedin_url = user.S_linkedin_url;
    model.S_github_url = user.S_github_url;
    model.S_twitter_url = user.S_twitter_url;

    return View(model);
}
```

Post action method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditProfile(Userdb editEntity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string username = User.Identity.Name;

        // Get the userprofile
        Userdb model =new Userdb();

        // Personal Details
        model.u_Firstname = editEntity.u_Firstname;
        model.u_lastname = editEntity.u_lastname;
        model.u_dob = editEntity.u_dob;
        model.u_mobile = editEntity.u_mobile;
        model.u_title = editEntity.u_title;
        ViewBag.u_Email = editEntity.u_Email;
        ViewBag.u_Firstname = editEntity.u_Firstname;
        ViewBag.u_lastname = editEntity.u_lastname;
        ViewBag.u_dob = editEntity.u_dob;
        ViewBag.u_mobile = editEntity.u_mobile;
        ViewBag.u_title = editEntity.u_title;

        // Education Details
        model.Degree_level = editEntity.Degree_level;
        model.Degree_name = editEntity.Degree_name;
        model.Starting_date = editEntity.Starting_date;
        model.Completion_date = editEntity.Completion_date;

        // Address Details
        model.country_name = editEntity.country_name;
        model.city_name = editEntity.city_name;
        model.Address = editEntity.Address;
        model.postal_code = editEntity.postal_code;

        // Social Link Details
        model.S_fb_url = editEntity.S_fb_url;
        model.S_linkedin_url = editEntity.S_linkedin_url;
        model.S_github_url = editEntity.S_github_url;
        model.S_twitter_url = editEntity.S_twitter_url;

        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // or whatever
    }
          
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
  @model Applicant.Models.Userdb
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditProfile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ProfileLayout.cshtml";
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "Users"))
    {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<body>
    <div class="container rounded bg-white mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 border-right">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center p-3 py-5"><img class="rounded-circle mt-5" width="150px" src="https://st3.depositphotos.com/15648834/17930/v/600/depositphotos_179308454-stock-illustration-unknown-person-silhouette-glasses-profile.jpg"><span class="font-weight-bold">@ViewBag.u_Firstname @ViewBag.u_lastname</span><span class="text-black-50">@ViewBag.u_Email</span><span> </span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 border-right">
                <div class="p-3 py-5">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                        <h4 class="text-right">Profile Settings</h4>
                    </div>
                    <h6>Personal Detail</h6>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Name</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.u_Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.u_Firstname } })</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Lastname</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.u_lastname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.u_lastname } })</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="labels">Gender</label><br />
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.u_Gender, "F")
                            Female
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.u_Gender, "M")
                            Male
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Designation</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.u_title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.u_title } })</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Mobile Number</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.u_mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.u_mobile } })</div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Address</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addres, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.Addres } })</div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Country</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.country_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.country_name } })</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">City</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.city_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.city_name } })</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Postal Code</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.postal_code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.postal_code } })</div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <h6>Education Detail</h6>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Degree Name</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Degree_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.Degree_name } })</div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Degree Level</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Degree_level, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.Degree_level } })></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Starting Date</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Starting_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.Starting_date } })</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Completion Date</label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Completion_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @ViewBag.Completion_date } })</div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />  
                    <div class="mt-5 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn" style="background-color:#5777ba; color:#fff;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="py-5">
                    <h6>Skills Detail</h6>
                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Skills</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="experience" value=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <h6>Skills Detail</h6>
                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Github Link</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="experience" value=""></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Linkedin Link</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="experience" value=""></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Twitter Link</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="experience" value=""></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Facebook Link</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="experience" value=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

}
```

Comment: At what point does it tell you the model is invalid? Is it in your `EditProfile` method, when you check the model state?

Comment: Also, what is the unique identifier of the `Userdb` object?

Comment: You have to show your view for this model.  I am looking forward.

Comment: You need to [**learn about AutoMapper**!!](https://automapper.org/)

Comment: @AnnL. yes when I click on button it is not updating data so I checked using breaking point and model is not valid

Comment: @AnnL. u_Email is unique identifier

Comment: @Serge sir updated View is added Kindly check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your view, which could account for the invalid model. If you post the definition of `Userdb`, complete with any metadata class (if those are still being used) we could see for sure.

First, you aren't putting the necessary `name` attribute in all your plain `input` fields. This means they won't get posted to the server as data, so the model binder won't be able to automatically populate those fields in your model.

Second, you've used `@Html.EditorFor()` in several places, with the identical properties being referenced. This means that what you put in the text box labeled "Name" will be assigned to the **u_Firstname** field on your model -- but so will what you've put in the "Gender" and "City" fields!
That means that the actual Gender and City properties on your model *won't* be populated.

Third, you say **u_Email** is the primary key, but it isn't even posted back from this form.

This brings me to what I suspect the real source of the problem is: your model isn't being fully populated from the form on posting, because you're not collecting all the data.  And I'd guess at least some of those properties have `Required` or other constraints on them that mean leaving them empty isn't allowed. (**u_Email** is a likely candidate, since it's the primary key.)

If you look at the contents of `editEntity` while debugging, it will probably be made very clear what's populated and what isn't.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail review.
1. I have updated view
2. Remaining Everything is fine all required field fill but still getting invalid ModelState.
3. EditEntity is populating all values whihch I want to change etc

Comment: You say "editEntity is populating all values which I want to change". But is it populating all the values you *need*, including the email address? Remember, what you're passing is supposed to be a valid `Userdb` object, suitable for saving, even if you're only using it as a data transfer object.

Comment: Your form has no input field that I can see that's mapped to the `u_Email`, even though you're displaying it (`spans` don't post back data), so it looks to me like the `editEntity` object will not have a populated `u_Email`, which I believe would be enough to have the model considered invalid.

Comment: One way around this, and to judge what the problem really is: create (temporarily) a smaller object, with just the fields you want to change, with NO validation attributes and not participating in EF.  Call it something like `UserViewModel`.

Comment: Make an instance of `UserViewModel` your model, and pass it back and forth, doing the value copying like you are now, but between the `Userdb` EF object and the model.  See if that makes the validation error go away.

Comment: I believe you'll still have the problem of not knowing on postback which `Userdb` record you're trying to edit, because you won't have the email address value. But you will be past the `IsValid` problem.

Answer (score -1):

replace this code

```
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

with

```
db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

the above whole code is true but the main problem is when you change the state of entity `EntityState.Modified` should be replaced with `System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` because `EntityState` is an object of `System.Data.Entity*` namespace

Comment: And how will that help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).